# Why is replace function not replacing my list with the new one?

Tags: python, pandas, list, machine-learning, replace

I used the replace function, and I tried replacing a single item list with another single item list, and it still is not working. I see no error, but there was no change either.
[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROirZ.jpg)

Somebody help me outa here.

Comment: Do. Not. Post. Screenshots. Of. Code.

Comment: Please edit the code directly into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is a string (object) type:

```
df['age'] = [['87.5'] if x == ['+75'] else x for x in df.age]
```

And now:

```
df
```

Would do the expected replacement.